# How to optimize network code for paravirtualized interface

Tags: tcp, network-programming, virtualbox

We have an application that solely run within VirtualBox guest (Linux) and only talks to the host (Mac OS X, Windows, Linux) via TCP sockets API by sending dozens of small messages (less than 100 bytes).

Are there any socket or (guest) OS settings that we can tweak to improve performance?